# How to merge multidimensional arrays into a single-dimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array and I need to flatten it into a single-dimensional array in PHP. I've tried using `array_merge` within a `foreach` loop, but it doesn't produce the desired result. Here's an example of the array structure:

```php
$nums = array (
  array(1, 2, 3),
  array(4, 5, 6),
  array(7, 8, 9)
);
```

This is the code I've attempted, but it returns an empty array:

```php
$newArr = [];
foreach ($nums as $value) {
   array_merge($newArr, $value);
}
```

My expectation is to obtain the following result:

```php
$newArr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

What is the correct approach to flatten a multidimensional array into a single-dimensional array in PHP? Is there a more efficient or alternative solution to achieve the desired output? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function **array_merge()** this way :

```
$newArr = array_merge(...$nums)
```

It would make your code lighter and avoid the use of a **foreach** loop.

Answer (score 0):

array_merge returns the results of the merge rather than acting on the passed argument like sort() does. You need to be doing:

```
$newArr = array_merge($newArr, $value);
```